# Modify binary data of a REG_MULTI_SZ

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

I know how to remotely modify the registry using C# (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws.aspx) but i can not for the life of me find how to modify the binary of a registry key on Win7.

I don't mean REG_BINARY, but when you are in regedit, right click a REG_MULTI_SZ key and click "Modify Binary Data..." Trying to achieve this http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/pendingfilerenameoperations-delete-file-t1715654.html

All i want do is add four 0's to the end. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zha3xws.aspx

Comment: as i said above that does not tell me how to modify the binary of a key